# Non-image data with cnn [Matlab Specific]

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I am trying to use a cnn to build a classifier for my data.
The training set is comprised of 2D numerical matrices which are not image data.

It seems that Matlab's cnns only work with image inputs:
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/imageinputlayer-class.html

Does anyone have experience with cnns and non-image data using Matlab's deep learning toolbox?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I first would like to understand why you want to use a CNN with non-image data? CNNs are specially good because they take into account information in the neighborhood. Unless your data has some kind of region pattern (like pixels that get together to create a pattern or sentences where word order is relevant) the CNN would not be the best approach to handle it.
That been said, if you still want to use it you could convert the matrix to images. I'm not sure if that would help though.

Function to convert: mat2gray